# How to fetch MySql data that match the logged in user criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, fetch, criteria

I have the PHP code that will fetch all users listed in the database but I only need the results to list users that have same matching company name as the logged in user.  The logged in user can add, edit and delete users of the same company name, in the database the field is labeled "company".

Here is my code to fetch all users but I need to change so the code only fetches the same "company" as the logged in user.

```
    <?php
                include_once 'connection.php';
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user_registration");
                ?>

                <?php
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                ?>
                  <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td>First</td>
                    <td>Last</td>
                    <td>Email ID</td>
                    <td>Password</td>
                     <td>Action</td>
                  </tr>
                <?php
                $i=0;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["first"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["last"]; ?></td>
                     <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo ($row["password"])?($row["password"]):('N/A'); ?></td>
                    <td><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" title='Update Record'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
                    <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" title='Delete Record'><i class='material-icons'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
```

Comment: Please share the schema here. Also, do you have a separate table for company or it's just a value in the user table?

Comment: I think you need to learn how `WHERE` works

Comment: ^ not "think" but "need to".

Comment: the database field "company" is in the same database table "user_registration".   I tried using the "WHERE" function but not sure how to list the logged in users "$company"

Comment: Do you have the logged-in user's company stored in the session or will you have to look it up at run time? Please provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: @waterloomatt   I think it is stored in session,  the user is logged in as an administrator to the website and has an ADMIN account webpage where they can add, change or modify other company users.  When the Admin user logs in they need to only fetch users from there company.  Currently it fetches all the database users, I need it to only fetch the logged in (admin users company users.

Comment: As other comments have pointed out, you need to limit the results using a _where_ clause. Ex. `SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE company = :company`, and then use the company from the session. Ex tutorial - https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @waterloomatt ...   thanks for the response.   will it be like this?     $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user_registration WHERE company='$company'");            How do I make sure it is getting the $company from the login session, can you provide tlines of code and where to add to this page?   I know it probably not that simple but anything will help solve this,  thanks

Comment: Although that might work, you are injecting user-supplied data directly into your query which exposes you to SQL injection. Look into the tutorial I posted. If that doesn't help, look into _mysqli prepated statements for select_.

Answer (score -1):

first you should save the  logged-in user data some where. you can make session in your login page after user logged-in. so do somthing like this in login page:

```
   include_once 'connection.php';
   session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
         $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `YOUR-USER-TABLE` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$passowrd");
        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $_SESSION['user'] = array(
        "ID" => $row['id'],
        "firstname" => $row['firstname'],
        "lastname" => $row['lasrname'],
        "email" => $row['email'],
        "company" => $row['company']
        );

        }
            
  } else{
      //return user to login page
        exit();
  }
```

then you can use this code:

```
    include_once 'connection.php';
    session_start();
    $users = array();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
      $company = $_SESSION['user']['company'];
      $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `user_registration` WHERE `company` = '$company'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $user= array(
               // get users data for example:
                "ID" => $row['id']
                "firstname" => $row['first'],
                "lastname" => $row['last'],
                "email" => $row['email'],
    //you can get every thing you need. it is not need to get password here

                );
    array_push($users, $user);
    }

    }
    else{
    //do everything that you do with no logged in user in this page
    }
```

now you can use `users` array in foreach loop and make your list.
I hope it make it clear for you. if there is something unclear please add comment.